# Model.association is returning nil, even with a valid id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

I have two models, Webcast, and Session. Webcast belongs to Session, and Session has one webcast. Also, I'm using STI with Session, it inherits from the model Schedulable, and has type = 'Session'.

I have a Session record, lets call it session, and a Webcast record, we'll call it webcast.

webcast.session_id is equal to session.id, and vice versa

yet, when I query the association, webcast.session I get nil. however, session.webcast returns the webcast record.

Also, I have tried querying Webcast.session on past Webcast record and it loads the associated record just fine.

Any ideas what could be happening here? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Queries:

(session.webcast)

```
Webcast Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `webcasts`.* FROM `webcasts` WHERE `webcasts`.`session_id` = 2679 LIMIT 1
```

(webcast.session)

```
Session Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schedulables`.* FROM `schedulables` WHERE `schedulables`.`import_id` IS NULL AND `schedulables`.`type` IN ('Session')  
AND `schedulables`.`id` = 2679 ORDER BY `schedulables`.`starts_at` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Also, I just noticed that if I load up the specific session record that the webcast belongs too, then reload the webcast record and try webcast.session again it will return the session record rather than nil.

Comment: Can we see your server log? Type in your IRB console `Webcast.first.session`, copy-paste the SQL queries triggered and do the same for `Session.first.webcast`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yeah, I updated my post with the sql queries, and some other useful information that I discovered.

Comment: There is an extra where statement (`WHERE schedulables.import_id IS NULL`) that might causes the non-appearance of the associated record. Are you using `default_scope`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am using a default scope. I checked the session record that belongs to the webcast and its import_id is nil, so it still should be loaded.  I did discover that if I load the session record first (just by doing Session.find id) and then load the webcast again and try webcast.session it will return the session record, rather than nil.

Comment: Wow, that's odd... I don't know what could provoke this (strange) behavior!